# SQLite INSERT or REPLACE, but only if something outside of the indexed columns is different?

Tags: sql, sqlite, replace, insert

If you have a 4 column table, with an index over columns 1, 2 and 3, and you have a row to enter that has the same data on the indexed columns as a saved record, is it possible to tweak an INSERT OR REPLACE to only replace if the column 4 data is different?

Reason being, I'm presenting the table with a bunch of data, some that is different, some the same (I have no choice about this), and I only want to update or add new data, and ignore anything that's the same.

So...

table with two saved records

```
firstName    lastName    age    height      
Jim          Thomson     82     62
Dave         Rogers      24     61
```

three records being presented in a parametric query:

```
Jim          Thomson     82     57
Dave         Rogers      24     61
Billy        Boyle       76     42
```

desired end result in table:

```
Jim          Thomson     82     57   << updated
Dave         Rogers      24     61   << ignored
Billy        Boyle       76     42   << inserted
```

Currently my insert or ignore attempts, quite rightly, only insert if there is any new data on columns 1, 2 or 3, and ignore otherwise, resulting in:

```
Jim          Thomson     82     62   << ignored
Dave         Rogers      24     61   << ignored
Billy        Boyle       76     42   << inserted
```

My alternative insert or replace attempts are overwriting ALL the saved records, regardless if there is no new data. It results in the correct data being entered, but I don't want to do it this way because I'm using .totalChanges to determine how many rows were affected, as I need to later build these affected rows into a query for uploading to an online database (the database I'm making the above changes to is a local one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a function to check if table contains a record in the name you are going to save already.

just like

```
alreadyExists bool (string _firstName, string _lastName)
{
    //implement a connection (con)

    //implement a command (cmd)

    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT firstName, lastName, age, height from yourTableName WHERE firstName = _firstName AND lastName = _lastName";

    //^ it will return firstName, lastName, age, and height from the table if it already contains a record in names you ve given in parameters

    //return true if command has returned something
    //or return false otherwise
}
```